# Make bison reduce to start symbol only if EOF is found

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I am using Bison with Flex.
I have the following rule in my Yacc input file:

```
program     : PROGRAM m2 declarations m0 block {cout << "Success\n"} ;
```

The problem is that if I have a program that is partially correct, but then there is some "garbage" before EOF, it will reduce according to the previous rule, report "success" and only then report an error.

I want to include EOF at the end of the rule above, but then, Flex would have to return EOF when it read `<<EOF>>`, and how would Bison know when to end the program?
Now, I have this in Flex:

```
<<EOF>>    {return 0;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that would do that:

First the lex file:

```
%{
#include "grammar.tab.h"
%}
%x REALLYEND
%option noinput nounput
%%
"END"                   { return END; }
.                       { return TOK; }
<INITIAL><<EOF>>        { BEGIN(REALLYEND); return EOP; }
<REALLYEND><<EOF>>      { return 0; }
%%

int yywrap(void)
{
        return 1;
}
```

In the `<INITIAL>` condition the end-of-file generates a token `EOP`. Note the explicit use of `<INITIAL>`, because otherwise the `<<EOF>>` will be used for all begin conditions. Then it switches to `<REALLYEND>` to generate the internal end-of-file "token" for bison.

The bison file could look like this:

```
%token END EOP TOK
%{
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror(char * msg)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
}
extern int yylex(void);
%}
%%
prog : END EOP { printf ("ok\n"); };
%%

int main(void)
{
        return yyparse();
}
```

The question in your title is a bit misleading as `bison` will always only reduce the *internal* start symbol if `EOF` is found, that is what the internal end-of-file token is for. The difference is that you wanted the action, printing `success`, in the grammar only to be executed after the `EOF` has been found and not before. That is, reduction of *your* start symbol.

Comment: when in doubt, use start conditions to fabricate the token you need. Excellent.